# error response json: Unexpected token ":"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have programming a Jquery Mobile application and I use an ajax request (method $.ajax(config)) to get my data.
Well when I use tha value "json" in the "dataType" property, I have an error javascript which tell me "Non-Access-Control-Orogin" in the header.
And when I use the value "jsonp" in the "dataType" property I have the response from the server but I get an error in the Json of response. "Unexpected token: :".
Any advice to resolve this problem?

This is the URL to connect my server:
http://rete.mywebsite.com/api3.0?param1=value1&param2=value2

This is my code to get the data in the Json format:
(Pardon the uncorrect tab)

$.ajax({
    url: MY_URL,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});

The json how I should get is similar this:
{
  "stazione_1":{
                            "name": "Brescia",
                            "temperature": "7.5",
                            ...
  }
}

But I get the unexpected token error in the console javascript of the browser (I use Chrome)...

I hope this will been of help...

Comment: Are you controlling the server? If yes, either setup [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or modify your server code to support JSONP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: What does the JSON look like? Do you actually get anything back?

Answer (score -1):

Either set the `CORS` headers on the server to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'*'`

OR

Change the `JSONP` so the `eval()` call does not break.

If you provide code, we might be better able to help...